# Firefox page load event very long

Tags: javascript, html, performance, firefox, web

I'm going to try to explain an issue that scratch my head...

When I open this [website](http://www.seanoe.org/) for the first time after opening **Firefox** (v43.0.3), the **UI freeze** during about **20 seconds** and I don't undersand why. For example you can see that the background image appear after almost 20 seconds...

So, I used firebug net panel to try to understand where the problem comes from and I notice that the page load event is very long but I can't see any tasks executing during this event.

[here is a screenshot of firebug Net Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDtFG.png)

When I open the website with Chrome it works fine, does someone has ever encounter that kind of problem ?

I hope that makes sense, thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW, I'm on Firefox 43.0.2 and it loads without any issues

Comment: this usually points to some plugin you have installed in firefox. try disabling all your plugins to see if it loads any faster, if it does you can then enable them one by one to see which one causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're making 31 requests (according to my NET panel - FireBug) which add to 323ms (at least in my case). Your background image is loading ~1s after. Maybe if you'd try to reorganize all that sprites you're requesting into less files - but it seems fair as loading time for me.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with Firebug itself. I had to turn it off and\or uninstall to get the page load normally on Firefox.

In my case it was an effect of problem between Firebug and Telerik Kendo JS Library.

Maybe you have a problem similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, indeed it seem's to comes from my firefox configuration or addons/plugins.

I use a Firefox pre-configured by my socity, so I installed a portable firefox to try if it works and the website is loading normaly.

Now I just have to find from whitch config or addons/plugins the problem comes from, thanks again !